# No border in Chrome, but it is in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap.
You will see my trouble at images

Screen from Chrome: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zi8eq7zposn6c9/chrome.png

Screen from FireFox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mrxarypnsjb63d/firefox.png (sorry, at the bottom there is another div with border)

My HTML(I think it is not needed to put all here):

```
    <div class="row menu">
    ...
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .menu{
    width:940px;
     height: 30px;
    border-width:0.5px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-color: grey;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: rgb(212,229,190);
     }
```

Comment: Did you try using a border of 1px to exclude rounding errors?

Comment: you are right man, I changed border width into 1px, and border appeared

Comment: How did you expect the browser to render half a pixel?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define a border less than `1px` because that's the smallest screen unit :) But doing this can cause some pain due to browsers' math engines - some will floor that value to `0` and some will round up to `1`. Which is exactly what happened to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped, here the solution as an official answer.

The problem is due to rounding errors because the border is set to half a pixel. By using at least 1px for border width, the problem will disappear (while the border appears).